# How can I make a repeat...until structure that has multiple exit parameters?

Tags: delphi-6

So my code looks like this

```
**Procedure DisplayMenu;
  Begin
    Repeat
      Writeln('Hello, ' ,PlayerName);
      Writeln('1. Be Guesser');
      Writeln('2. Let The Computer Guess');
      Writeln('9. Quit');
      Readln(MainMenuChoice);
    *Until MainMenuChoice=(1) or (2) or (9);*
  End; //Procedure//**
```

And I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me where I have gone wrong.

I think the error is with the Until MainMenuChoice=(1) or (2) or (9); part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the value of `MainMenuChoice` to the value created by `OR`'ing the bits of the three test values together, which produces 11.  So your code is actually doing this:

```
Until MainMenuChoice = 11;
```

To compare it again the three individual values, use a Set instead:

```
Until MainMenuChoice in [1, 2, 9];
```

However, assuming `MainMenuChoice` is a `Char` then `Readln()` is going to return the character that the user actually typed, not its numeric value, so use this instead:

```
Until MainMenuChoice in ['1', '2', '9'];
```

Comment: I also have a problem with an error 'record, object or class type required'. Would you be able to help me with this also?

Comment: What is `MainMenuChoice` actually declared as? Please update your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: MainMenuChoice is a global variable, declared as an integer.